# Linux SPI from the terminal

Tags: terminal, embedded-linux, spi

I am very new to embedded linux development but need to interface with a microcontroller via SPI.

I am using a VAR-SOM-MX8M-MINI and yocto Dunfell (kernel 5.4.142). I can access the spi from /dev/spidev0.2 and can output data by just echoing to this device

echo "test" > /dev/spidev0.2

This works fine, I can see the waveform on a logic analyser and I can see the microcontroller respond. However I do not know how to access the received data from the Linux side. For uart devices I could cat the /dev/ file but that doesn't work for SPI I get the response "cat: -: Message too long"

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You see waveforms for some settings of the SPI and due to that you can't confirm that the message is what you actually want to send. SPI requires to communicate via IOCTL interface and it also requires one of the peer to be **a controller** and the other(s) -- **peripheral(s)**. Linux only recently started gaining **peripheral mode** support for the SPI controllers (only few nowadays supported). Read https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/introduction-to-spi-interface.html,  http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Groking%20the%20Linux%20SPI%20Subsystem.pdf

Comment: And code examples: https://www.emcraft.com/som/stm32f7-212/accessing-spi-devices-in-linux, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/spi/spidev_test.c